# What does the "monkey head" icon mean in the challenge mode menu?

Tags: super-monkey-ball-banana-mania

Next to each difficulty in challenge mode, there are two icons that can be either unlit or lit.

[image: monkey ball challenge mode difficulty options screenshot]

It's obvious to me that the checkmark icon means you've completed a playthrough of the matching difficulty.

But what does the "monkey head" icon mean? I achieved it in my *Casual* and *Expert* playthroughs, but not my *Master* playthrough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be related to the missions, as you can see in this screenshot I took from a youtuber:

[image]

Next to each mission you can see the "monkey token" that means the mission is achieved, every mission was completed, so Reverse Mode now has that monkey icon, too.